# How do I add an array to a url or send a post array?

Tags: php, session, post, curl

Ok so i have a curl request I am trying to make.

```
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://someurl.com/shop_pos/index.php?route=module/cart/ajax_get_all_products");

// Do a POST
$items = 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_SESSION['cart']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

The contents or `$_SESSION['cart']` is

```
Array
(
  [155] => 1
  [78] => 1
)
```

I need to send this data either as post data or a get variable...any suggestions

on the catching function

```
public function ajax_get_all_products(){
    $this->language->load('module/cart');
    $all_products = $this->cart->getProducts();
    $data_returned = json_encode($all_products);
    echo "<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST, true)."</pre>";
    echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
    $this->response->setOutput($data_returned, $this->config->get('config_compression'));
}
```

I dont get the array I set over. The two files are on the same server btw

Comment: have you got a session_start() in your cURL script file?

Comment: yes i do session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_start();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('items' => $_SESSION['cart']));
```

try this:

```
$post_data = http_build_query(array('items' => $_SESSION['cart']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: so i tried curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('items' => implode(",", $_SESSION['cart'])));
 but it only returns      [items] => 1,1 which is half of what i need

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$post = "";
   $amp = "";
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
       $post .= $amp . $key . "=" . urlencode($value);
       $amp = "&";                        
   }
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use php serialize and unserialize function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php